# R - Escaped comma in command line argument

Tags: r, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to parse a comma delimited vector as a command line argument. However, I would like to ignore all escaped commas.

I.e.

When running the following

```
#test.R
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print (args)
print (unlist(strsplit(args, ",", perl=TRUE))) # also doesn't work with perl=FALSE
```

and running the following:

```
Rscript test.R "w1,w2\,w3,w4"
```

This produces the following output:

```
[1] "w1,w2\\,w3,w4"
[1] "w1"   "w2\\" "w3"   "w4"
```

The output that I expected was:

```
[1] "w1,w2\,w3,w4"
[1] "w1"   "w2,w3"   "w4"
```

I have also tried out a number of libraries including optparse and argparser, but I get a similar output there as well...

Thus I would appreciate if someone could help me in ignoring escaped characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is of help: First, replace the escape sequence with a character without ",", e.g.

```
args <- "w1,w2\\,w3,w4" #  commandArgs(TRUE)
s1 <- gsub("\\,", "#", args, fixed=TRUE)
```

Then perform `strsplit`:

```
s2 <- unlist(strsplit(s1, ","))
```

Finally undo the replacement

```
s3 <- gsub("#", ",", s2) # expected result
```

This requires that you have an escape character (in the example "#") you are sure is not passed as argument otherwise.

A more direct way is not to use `strsplit`:

```
pos <- unlist(gregexpr("[^\\\\],", args, perl=TRUE)) # args is as above
substring(args, c(1, pos+2), c(pos,nchar(args))) # expected result
```

Comment: Many Thanks, but I wanted to know if there was 'pure' R way of doing this - i.e. without doing a work-around... I'll accept the answer if no-one else comes up with something.

Comment: Updated the answer for a more robust solution.